# Generate VC++ .aps file in build directory and not source directory

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, cmake, resource-files

I am building a VC++ project in Visual Studio 9.0 with CMake. The project is built out-of-source. The project has a GUI component and when the resource file (.rc) is compiled it creates a binary version of the file (.aps).

However, the .aps file is being created in the source directory adjacent to the .rc file and not in the build directory.

How can I have the binary .aps file generated in the build directory?

I want to keep my build completely out-of-source to avoid polluting it and inadvertently committing it. I would rather not resort to adding this one file to an ignore file in my version control and have it built in the build directory.

Comment: It is a noise file that is generated by the resource editor.  You only ever get it when you start editing resources, it speeds up the next editing session.  It is not part of the project, it should not be created by CMake and you have no control over its location.

Comment: @HansPassant I understand what the file is and that it is being created by MSVS and not CMake. However, do you have a citation or reference for your claim that "you have no control over its location"?

Comment: Hans Passant is a visual studio loremaster. He IS the citation.

However, I suggest you hexedit resedit.dll to replace the unicode string ".aps" with 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x00 which sufficed for me to make it stop succeeding in creating that file in the first place.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue in VS2017, but this time the file doesn't even have an extension, so I can't just add it to my `.gitignore`

Comment: No. Never found an answer. Just had to ignore the file.